# Apache rewrites not chaining right with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, https

Si I have 2 apache rewrites that seem to work well on their own but not in conjunction with each other. One redirects http traffic to https and the other appends .php to requests without an extension, but it's having trouble doing both at the same time, ends up 404.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} projects
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/projects/$1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this,

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^projects
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: no luck, and that first rewrite rule is missing a /

Comment: It's bouncing to 404.

Comment: So:
http ://www.example.com/projects/page.php works,
https ://www.example.com/projects/page works,
but http ://www.example.com/projects/page ends up 404. (spaces to get around autoformatting.

Comment: I don't understand you want https or not?